# Convert a map to a json object in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular2-template

I am currently developing an app with Angular 4. I want to know if it is possible to convert a map to json in angular ? 
this is my map stucture

```
  selectedLanguageDetails.set("languageName", element.languageName);
          selectedLanguageDetails.set("languageCode", element.languageCode);
          selectedLanguageDetails.set("internalId", element.internalId);
```

json structure

```
 "languages": [
    {
    "internalId": 101,
    "languageCode": "ms",
    "languageName": "Malay"
    }
    ],
```

Comment: In this case if you are just using strings for keys would you not be best just using a object `selectedLanguageDetails={}` and then you could just JSON.stringify it. Would save a lot of leg work. Your can also set object keys with dynamic data using '[a]: 'test''. I have never found a need to use Map over {}. Its not like java where you have to new up Maps etc.

Answer (score 5):

To convert to an object - spread the Map to get an array of [key, value] pairs, and [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to an object.

To convert to a string - Instead of reduce, use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert each pair to a string, and [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the result:

```js
const selectedLanguageDetails = new Map(); 
 
 selectedLanguageDetails.set("languageName", "English");
          selectedLanguageDetails.set("languageCode", "en");
          selectedLanguageDetails.set("internalId", 15);
          
const obj = [...selectedLanguageDetails].reduce((o, [key, value]) => (o[key] = value, o), {});

const string = [...selectedLanguageDetails].map(([key, value]) => `${key}:${value}`).join(', ');

console.log(obj);

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 2):

For converting Map to JSON object or string you can use below code.

```
let jsonObject = {};  
selectedLanguageDetails.forEach((value, key) => {  
       jsonObject[key] = value  
});  
string jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
```